# TextUtils.isEmpty(null) returns false

Tags: android

What am I missing? This doesn't make any sense:

[image: screenshot of Android Studio]

Why is `TextUtils.isEmpty(null)` returning `false`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced this same issue while writing my unit test. The problem was I had following setting in my Gradle:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

By default android code returned default value, while running my unit tests.
Just get rid of that and you should be fine.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Looks like Android team is already aware of this "We are aware that the default behavior is problematic when using classes like Log or TextUtils and will evaluate possible solutions in future releases." http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.- thx

Comment: Thanks, was getting furious at this odd (or so I thought) behaviour!

Comment: 2023 here, and this behavior is still gaslighting programmers into thinking we've gone mad XD

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using Kotlin,
You can replace

```
TextUtils.isEmpty()
```

with

```
isNullOrEmpty
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-empty.html