# java.lang.NullPointerException for null input in null safe static method

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, powermockrunner

```
@Test
fun isEmpty_null_true(){
    Assert.assertEquals(StringUtils.isEmpty(null),true)
}

public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable String value) {
    return (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || value.trim().isEmpty());
}
```

All test methods except above one are working and passed. I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` for this one. The implementation of `StringUtils.isEmpty()` is also mentioned above. `StringUtils` class is written in Java whereas test case file is written in Kotlin.

Comment: Please share StringUtils class

Comment: @ShaluTD cannot share complete class, it belongs to production code. Please share your query.

Comment: Check for value==null before use. Before you trim.

Comment: @blackapps `TextUtils.isEmpty()` does that.

Comment: Why didnt you tell before? Then check for null before you call isEmpty. And you did not show code for that function so what do you expect from us?

Comment: @blackapps it is a android system method, so i didn't specify. `public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
        return str == null || str.length() == 0;
    }`

Comment: Are `StringUtils` and `TextUtils` the same?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu
`StringUtils.isEmpty` and `TextUtils.isEmpty` has only one difference, which is `trim` method.

Comment: do you run this test as instrumented or local unit test?

Comment: Can you please: 1. Post entire stack trace. 2. If possible, run on JDK 14 with `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages` 3. What is @Nullable (show fully qualified name)

Comment: Is your question "why is this throwing a `NullPointerException`?". Or is your question "given that I know that this will throw a `NullPointerException`, how do I write a test for it?".

Comment: It should not throw NullPointerException due to null check written in method. I need answer to make it work. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The complete solution, I have got-**
Due to default values set in app/build.gradle, I was getting false returned from `TextUtils.isEmpty()` which was not expected by me.

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

**Reference -** [TextUtils.isEmpty(null) returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862072/textutils-isemptynull-returns-false)
I cannot change the value in build.gradle file, so I needed the solution for my unit test method only. There is a way to provide implementation to `TextUtils.isEmpty()` method and get the real returned value.

```
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any(CharSequence.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                CharSequence a = (CharSequence) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                return !(a != null && a.length() > 0);
            }
        });
   }
```

**Reference -** [Need help to write a unit test using Mockito and JUnit4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763289/need-help-to-write-a-unit-test-using-mockito-and-junit4/36441930)

I got the same problem with `android.graphics.Color.parseColor()` so above solution applies to all classes lies in `android` package.

Comment: As mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62936560/4936904), you used the power mock approach as a solution which is clearly a bad practice as the real app will crash with null values yet the bounty is allocated to answer that suggests a code change, can you please justly this?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh - Bounty is given to that answer because it has a link of why TextUtils.isEmpty(null) returns false (due to gradle default values param). It was my real project problem and that answer helped me in finding solution. It didn't have proper explanation so I wrote my answer too.

Comment: Have you tried running tests without `unitTests.returnDefaultValues` and with power mock implementation?, your mocked testutil,isempty should return false with powermock but `value.trim()` should throw an exception. if your test is passing, you have successfully implemented a useless test.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in this `StringUtils.isEmpty()`  method itself because sometime [TextUtils.isEmpty(null) returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862072/textutils-isemptynull-returns-false) at that time you are passing `value` as `null` then you are invoking `trim()` method on the `null` value that is causing the `java.lang.NullPointerException` modify the method like this to avoid `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```java
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable String value) {
        return (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || (value != null && value.trim().isEmpty()));
    }
```

Comment: I got your point but just to make unit test pass, I cannot change method implementation. I have seen link attached. Can you provide a way to really call TextUtils method or mock completely only for these methods. Not for all.

Comment: @HarishGyanani: "I cannot change method implementation" -- you do not have a choice. Your method claims to support `null` as a value, and it does not. You could change `@Nullable` to `@NotNull` and remove the unit test, or you could rewrite the method to be `null`-safe, as in this answer.

Comment: Change in `Nullable` to `NotNull` is also a change in code so the tests should be according to the current code as OP is only doing the testing part.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `||` operator will invoke the code on both sides (to get one true value) and `null.trim()..` will cause the exception.

Since the expected behavior of `StringUtils.isEmpty` method is to throw an exception when a `null` value is being passed so you should write the unit test to expect an exception with `null` value as:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException::class)
fun isEmpty_null_exception(){
    StringUtils.isEmpty(null)
}
```

here `excepted` is used to assert that this test method throws a `NullPointerException` exception.

Note: [Using mock for StringUtils.isEmpty static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847837/java-lang-nullpointerexception-for-null-input-in-null-safe-static-method#comment111281704_62882601) method is done with [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) framework but this will violate the purpose of testing to test the actual behavior of code so use the above-recommended approach to verify exception. You may want to create a mocked input variable and mock `trim` method but then you can simply use a non-null input string, won't be any difference.

Comment: if first condition is false then second condition is evaluated. "OR" operator works like this.

Comment: @HarishGyanani The details in this answer is specific to the current post, not general :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe instead of:
`value.trim().isEmpty()`
try this: `value.trim().equals("")`